# What do the certain files do after creating an empty project in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

After running a "hello world" application once, I see several files appearing in the (let's name it Apple) project's folder:
- a Debug folder with a .exe and two "source browser database" files, all named Apple;
- a folder Apple with a Project file, a Project filters file and the source file itself
- this Apple folder also has a debug folder with many items in it (should I care about them?).
- Directly in the "main" folder is a solution file and an SQL server compact edition database file.
What are their roles? Should I care about them (about which exactly)?

Comment: You should care about all of them, if you are working in Visual Studio. You can delete folders named Debug/, Release/, or ip/ and they will be regenerated. The .filter file is considered important enough that it is recommended to check it in, but typically it is no big deal if it gets deleted. The .user file contains stuff important to you personally. You need to learn quite a bit more if you don't know what the .exe does - after all, that's your program!

Comment: @dwn Very thorough. Posted that as a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should care about all of them, if you are working in Visual Studio.

You can delete folders named `Debug`, `Release`, or `ipch` and they will be regenerated, as all files in them are derived from other files in your project.

The `.filters` file holds the assignment of source files to folders in the solution. It's considered important enough that it is recommended to check it in, but typically it is no big deal if it gets deleted.

The `.user` and `.suo` files contain stuff important to you personally, and should not be checked in to source control.

You need to learn quite a bit more if you don't know what the `.exe` does - after all, that's your program!